# Transmission fluid level when engine stopped, and when engine is just turn on, and when the engine is hot?

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission, camry, transmission-fluid

My car is a 1994 toyota camry LE 3.0. I just changed the transmission fluid today.

I add the new fluid to the level up to the full (upper) level of the cold (C) range scale.

I drive the car for 15 minutes, the car runs very smooth and show nothing unusual from the changing of the speed in RPM or speed. I came back to measure the fluid level. I pull out the fluid stick to read the level. On one side of the stick, it shows almost no fluid, but on the other side of the stick, it shows fluid level exceeded higher than the upper scale of the HOT range.

Can you tell me is this normal? Or what is the problem there?

Comment: You need the manufacturer’s instructions for checking the level... otherwise you could make some expensive mistakes...