# automatic transmission fluid level

Tags: transmission

my fluid level when cold in the mornings is 3/4" above hot notches on dipstick for the auto transmission when engine not going , when I start the engine and look again it has dropped to the cold notch but eventually returns to the top hot notch, is this normal or should it be on the bottom cold notch similar to the engine in the morning? does the fluid in the oil cooler drain back into the sump giving a higher reading when cold?

Comment: The same phenomenon is observed with engine oil. If you measure engine oil level immediately after turning the engine off, you get a false reading (the level appears too low). I would give it at least 5 minutes for the oil to drain back. Leaving just a comment because I don't have any experience with automatic transmissions (have never owned a traditional torque converter based AT car).

Comment: See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/68697/10976 and many other similar on here...